# How to represent a $5$ digit number that has $62$ choices per digit?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

If you have a $5$ digit number that can be 0-9A-Za-z how would you represent that?

```
total_number_of_records = 5 digits * (10 + 26 + 26) ^ 5
```

I want to find out how many possible combinations you can come up with if you can use $0-9$, A-Z and lowercase A-Z for each digit in a $5$ digit number. Is that right?

Here is a picture of my calculator:

[image]

I've typed $62$ and now I want to increase the exponent to $5$.

Comment: Are you asking **how many** length 5 strings exist which consist of alphanumeric characters 0,1,...,9,a,b,...,z,A,B,...,Z?  For example 1bZz2 and A8jeE, etc...

Comment: Yeah. How many possible combinations if you are allowed if you can use 0-9, A-Z and lowercase A-Z in a 5 digit number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your count. If each character (notice it's not really a number) can appear more than once, the total number of strings is simply $(10 + 26 + 26)^{5}.$ You do not need to multiply this result by $5$.

Comment: OK That looks right.

Comment: Ok thank you but now I do not know how to enter that in a calculator. Do you know how to do exponents on the calculator? I added a picture of what I see.

Comment: The $x^y$ button is the one you want.  You type $62\ x^y\ 5\ =$

Comment: With that $62$ on your screen, click the "$x^{y}$" button (fourth button on the second row), enter your exponent (for this problem, it would be $5$), and press the equal sign to get your answer. Glad to help!